# I'm going to use https to communicate with cnosdb. Does anyone know how to use the --ssl parameter in cnosdb-cli?

Tags: cnosdb

I found that cnosdb-cli has two parameters:

```
--ssl and --unsafe-ssl
```

I know that `cnosdb-cli --unsafe-ssl` can be used to achieve an authenticated https connection, but I do not know how to use --ssl?

Comment: Have you tried adding --ssl and connecting?  Does it give errors or work?  Cause it sounds like you don't have to specify any parameters for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
$ cnosdb-cli -h
Command Line Client for Cnosdb.
...
...
      --ssl
          Use HTTPS connection
      --unsafe-ssl
          Allow unsafe HTTPS connections
      --cacert <FILE>
          Use the specified certificate file to verify the connection peer. The certificate(s) must be in PEM format
...
...
```